# Average sleep interval in PHP

Tags: php, time, sleep, average, period

I need to get average sleep interval from following data:

- 22:00-06:00
- 00:00-08:00
- 02:00-10:00

=> **expected**: 00:00-08:00

- 22:00-06:00
- 00:00-08:00
- 02:00-10:00
- 04:00-08:00

=> **expected**: 01:00-08:00

The problem is oscillation around midnight, where part is under 00:00 and part over 00:00.
Simple mean 22+00+02+04 doesn't work. I could count number of times over midnight (3 in this case) and if it's more than those before midnight, I should add 25 co compensate. *But this doesn't count with those people, who work at night and go sleep around 8-14*!

My theory is: First, *somehow* I need found peak, something like the most frequented area (e.g., in 9-10 there is 5 record, in 10-11, there is 3 etc.) and then I can decide co compensate border values by adding 24 hours.

What do you think?

Comment: There is no need to sleep for developers...

Comment: Could you use 0 as base value representing 00:00 so that 22:00 means -2 and 01:00 equals  +1? Do you need minutes as well?

Comment: http://www.dustincurtis.com/sleep.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the assumption that the person is not sleeping more than 24 hours, then make a method to calculate like so (pseudo code):

```
calculateSleepTime(sleepTime, wakeupTime) {
    if (sleepTime > wakeupTime) {
        return (24 - sleepTime) + wakeupTime;
    } else {
        return wakeupTime - sleepTime;
    }
}

averageSleepTime(sleepTimesArray) {
    totalSleptTime = 0;
    totalTimesSlept = 0;

    foreach (oneSleepTime in sleepTimesArray) { 
        totalTimesSlept++;
        totalSleptTime += calculateSleepTime(oneSleepTime);
    }

    return totalSleptTime / totalTimesSlept;
}
```

After you get the average sleep time, calculate either the average sleep time, or average wake up time, and do addition/substraction to find your interval. The alternative to this is finding the average sleep time and the average wakeup time (taking relative to midnight times into account).

Answer (score 1):

What about taking into account relative difference with midnight ?
The result would be (-2+0+2+4)/4 = 00:45

Comment: Huh, 11:00 and 13:00 would make (11 - 11)/ 2 = 0, not 12.

Answer (score 0):

Determine a lower limit where you can say

> Okay, people won't go to sleep this time of the day, if I get this time, it must mean they worked all night and only sleep now

and if the time is below that limit, add 24 hours to both start and finish.